# What is a CMAF sample?

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, mse

This article (https://bitmovin.com/what-is-cmaf-threat-opportunity/
) describes that a sample is "all the data associated with a single timestamp".

Is it the same as a frame, or how can I imagine that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is basically the same thing as a frame. They call it a sample however because some media types, like subtitles, and other pieces of timed metadata are not really “frames” in the traditional sense.